# Create read action as custom one?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I know there is a inbuilt action called news.reads but I need to create the same action as I need to have my application name on the activity items, can I create same Read action as custom one?.

Comment: Pardon me? What exactly do You want us to help You with? Can You provide us with some code example that You tried? This question is totally unclear!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I saw that Facebook only allows developers to create default action types. Eg. in App settings, we can add new action to the Open graph, so what I did was instead of using news.reads created a new action called Read. But it seems FB is not allowing me to create one as they didn't approve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built-in read action. It will attribute it to your app anyways.

Comment: Yes, but it will not create activity feeds in news feeds as custom action does, so I hope to use a custom Read action instead of news.reads is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean it won't make activity feeds? If there is a global verb you should semantically use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom read action, Facebook will reject it when it comes to approving the action. Something along the lines of:

`Your Action failed the criteria: You are trying to submit a custom
action which is not permitted. Please delete this action and submit a
built-in version of this action instead.`